# Removing days before and after matching row

Tags: r

I am able to remove rows that match between two data frames, df1 and df2, with some code kindly furnished by @Eric Fail:

`df1[!(apply(df1[1:2], 1, toString) %in% apply(df2[1:2], 1, toString)), ]`

or with a `dplyr` solution by @steveb

`df1 %>% filter( ! ((date == df2$date) & (ticker == df2$ticker)) )`

However, I realized I need to remove not only the shared row like this:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ticker = c("MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"), 
date = c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04"), stringsAsFactors=F)
df1

  ticker       date
1   MSFT 2016-01-01
2   MSFT 2016-01-02
3   MSFT 2016-01-03
4   MSFT 2016-01-04

df2 <- data.frame(ticker = c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT", "FB"), 
date = c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03"), stringsAsFactors=F)
df2

  ticker       date
1   AAPL 2016-01-01
2   GOOG 2016-01-01
3   MSFT 2016-01-02
4     FB 2016-01-03

df3 

  ticker       date
1   MSFT 2016-01-01
2   MSFT 2016-01-03
3   MSFT 2016-01-04
```

But also the day before, and the day after, the specified row. So my final df would be:

```
  ticker       date
1   MSFT 2016-01-04
```

Notice, `3   MSFT 2016-01-02` was the match, so that row needs to be removed, along with the day before and day after, `3   MSFT 2016-01-01` and `3   MSFT 2016-01-03`

Example with two matches:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ticker = c("MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"),
                  date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04")),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(ticker = c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT", "MSFT"),
                  date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01","2016-01-02")),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
```

Goal output:

```
ticker       date
4   MSFT 2016-01-04
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could convert the strings to dates so you can add and subtract the days

```
df1 <- data.frame(ticker = c("MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"),
                  date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04")),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(ticker = c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT", "FB"),
                  date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03")),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)


(m <- df2[(df2$date %in% df1$date) & (df2$ticker %in% df1$ticker), ])
#   ticker       date
# 3   MSFT 2016-01-02

df1[!(df1$date %in% (m$date + c(-1,0,1))), ]

#   ticker       date
# 4   MSFT 2016-01-04
```

edit - for multiple matches, just apply the `function(x)` across each date

```
df1 <- data.frame(ticker = c("MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT", "MSFT"),
                  date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04")),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)
df2 <- data.frame(ticker = c("AAPL", "GOOG", "MSFT", "MSFT"),
                  date = as.Date(c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2016-01-01","2016-01-02")),
                  stringsAsFactors=F)

(m <- df2[(df2$date %in% df1$date) & (df2$ticker %in% df1$ticker), ])
#   ticker       date
# 3   MSFT 2016-01-01
# 4   MSFT 2016-01-02

df1[!(df1$date %in% (sapply(m$date, function(x) x + c(-1,0,1)))), ]
#   ticker       date
# 4   MSFT 2016-01-04
```

Comment: Extremely elegant. It works wonderfully, except when there are two or more matches in which case I get `Warning message:
In unclass(e1) + unclass(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length` and only the last match is removed. I tried to make a for loop which operates only if there are more than two matches but I imagine there's a much better way. I added another example with two matches instead of one to my original question.

Comment: @RyGuy try `df1[!(df1$date %in% (sapply(m$date, function(x) x + c(-1,0,1)))), ]`

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you.